# Parsing HTML table using BeautifulSoup and Python

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse tables from http://www.immihelp.com/h1b-sponsoring-companies-database/display-2-2010.html using BeautifulSoup. However I am able to get it to work. I am new to BeautifulSoup and Python, any help would be much appreciated.

```
import urllib.request as urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

contenturl = "http://www.immihelp.com/h1b-sponsoring-companies-database/display-2-2010.html"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(contenturl).read())

table = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'scroll'})

rows = table.findAll('tr')
for tr in rows:
cols = tr.findAll('td')
if 'content-table-row' in cols[0]['class']:
    # currency row
    name, job, title, wage, town, state, zip = [c.text for c in cols]
    print(name, job, title, wage, town, state, zip)
```

Comment: What is the error you get, what is wrong with your code ?

Comment: The code above is not correct Python syntax.  Check your indentation under `for tr in rows:`.